# Build nested json data from variable with looping with jq using bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm trying to create a dynamic json data using jq, but I don't know how to write it when involving loop. I can do this in normal bash writing a sequence string

Here is the example code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Here I declare 2 arrays just to demonstrate. Each values pairs between `disk_ids` and `volume_ids` cannot have the same value. If one has value, the other must null.

disk_ids=(111 null 222 333)
volume_ids=(null 444 null null)
json_query_data=""

# Now example I want to loop through the above 2 arrays and create json. In real application I already have the above arrays that is looping where I can access using $disk_id and $volume_id.

for disk_id in "${disk_ids[@]}"; do
  for volume_id in "${volume_ids[@]}"; do
    json_query_data=$(jq -n --argjson disk_id "$disk_id" --argjson volume_id "$volume_id" '{
                          devices: {
                                             sda: {"disk_id": $disk_id, "volume_id": $volume_id },
                                             sdb: {"disk_id": $disk_id, "volume_id": $volume_id },
                                             sdc: {"disk_id": $disk_id, "volume_id": $volume_id },
                                             sdd: {"disk_id": $disk_id, "volume_id": $volume_id },
                                          }}')

  done
done
```

As you can see that is definitely NOT the output that I want, and my code writing logic is not dynamic. The final output should produce the following json when I `echo "${json_query_data}"`:

```
{
    devices: {
               sda: {"disk_id": 111, "volume_id": null },
               sdb: {"disk_id": null, "volume_id": 444 },
               sdc: {"disk_id": 222, "volume_id": null },
               sdd: {"disk_id": 333, "volume_id": null },
}}
```

I have not seen any example online regarding looping with variable when creating json data with `jq`. Appreciate if someone can help. Thanks.

UPDATE:

I must use for loop inside bash to create the json data. Because the sample array `disk_ids` and `volume_ids` that I provided in the code were just example, In real application I already able to access the variable `$disk_id` and `$volume_id` for each for loop counter. But how do I use this variables and create the json output that fill up all the data above inside that for loop?

The json example is taken from: [linode API here](https://www.linode.com/docs/api/linode-instances/#linode-boot-into-rescue-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The looping/mapping can also be accomplished in jq:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

disk_ids=(111 null 222 333)
volume_ids=(null 444 null null)

jq -n --arg disk_ids "${disk_ids[*]}" --arg volume_ids "${volume_ids[*]}" '
  [$disk_ids, $volume_ids | . / " " | map(fromjson)]
  | transpose | {devices: with_entries(
      .key |= "sd\([. + 97] | implode)"
      | .value |= {disk_id: first, volume_id: last}
    )}
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/kIdNSmrc3h7)

Or, if you can already provide the letters in the same way:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

disk_ids=(111 null 222 333)
volume_ids=(null 444 null null)
letters=(a b c d)

jq -n --arg disk_ids "${disk_ids[*]}" --arg volume_ids "${volume_ids[*]}" --arg letters "${letters[*]}" '
  [$disk_ids, $letters, $volume_ids | . / " " ] | .[0,2] |= map(fromjson)
  | transpose | {devices: with_entries(
      .key = "sd\(.value[1])"
      | .value |= {disk_id: first, volume_id: last}
    )}
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mfmn0owwCKA)

Output:

```json
{
  "devices": {
    "sda": {
      "disk_id": 111,
      "volume_id": null
    },
    "sdb": {
      "disk_id": null,
      "volume_id": 444
    },
    "sdc": {
      "disk_id": 222,
      "volume_id": null
    },
    "sdd": {
      "disk_id": 333,
      "volume_id": null
    }
  }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

> I must use for loop inside bash to create the json data.

If you insist on doing this in a bash loop, how about:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

disk_ids=(111 null 222 333)
volume_ids=(null 444 null null)
json='{"devices": {}}'

for i in ${!disk_ids[@]}
do
  json="$(
    jq --argjson disk_id "${disk_ids[$i]}" --argjson volume_id "${volume_ids[$i]}" '
      .devices |= . + {"sd\([length + 97] | implode)": {$disk_id, $volume_id}}
    ' <<< "$json"
  )"
done
echo "$json"
```

Or, with letters included:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

disk_ids=(111 null 222 333)
volume_ids=(null 444 null null)
letters=(a b c d)
json='{"devices": {}}'

for i in ${!disk_ids[@]}
do
  json="$(
    jq --argjson disk_id "${disk_ids[$i]}" --argjson volume_id "${volume_ids[$i]}" --arg letter "${letters[$i]}" '
      .devices["sd\($letter)"] += {$disk_id, $volume_id}
    ' <<< "$json"
  )"
done
echo "$json"
```

Comment: What if I want to use for loop? Because the sample data that I wrote there were just example, Can this be done in a for loop where each loop I have the value of disk_id and volume_id respectively? If I use this solution, I will not be able to use the data $disk_id and $volume_id in my original code.

Comment: @KalibZen They use curly braces with objects. Note the object fields, e.g. `"disk_id"`

Comment: Thank you I think I wrote a wrong example. I will redo

Comment: Updated my code thank you for correcting that one. I wish to see example how to create the json query inside for loop. I must use for loop as the variable $disk_id and $volume_id are already generated in for loop for me to use. Can we build that json file straight from the data using jq?

Comment: May I know what is `sd\([length + 97`?

Comment: It's called [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C%28foo%29). You provide a static string `"…"`, but everything between escaped parens `\(…)` will be evaluated and stringified. If you mean the content, `implode` converts ascii codepoints to strings, so by adding 97 to the index you generate lowercase letters `a`, `b` … which will be appended to `sd`, forming the field names `sda`, `sdb` …

Comment: Sorry, I have a last request on what you explained above. My real application don't generate that sda, sdb, sdc and sdd but I already have the access into the variable in each loop counter as well example I have access it using the variable`$disk_letter` (which produces a single character `a` or `b` or `c` or `d`). How can I replace this inside that loop?

Comment: I made it by replacing the above code to `.devices |= . + {"sd\($disk_letter)": {$disk_id, $volume_id}}` do you think this should be ok?

Comment: @KalibZen You can even shortcut `|= . +` to `+=`. See my update.

Comment: @KalibZen Why does it _have_ to loop in bash? There are looping and reduction constructs in `jq` that does effectively the same thing processing the intermediate result. See `foreach` and `reduce`.

Comment: @JeffMercado I'm not sure how to implement that. Lack of example how it works.

Comment: @KalibZen A `reduce` example could go like `reduce transpose[] as [$disk_id, $letter, $volume_id] ({}; .devices."sd\($letter)" = {$disk_id, $volume_id})` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/eGRRdVR8cP-)

Comment: @pmf what if we don't want to build a nested json what if i want the data to be just `{ "sda": {
      "disk_id": 111,"volume_id": null},"sdb": {"disk_id": null,"volume_id": 444},"sdc": { "disk_id": 222,"volume_id": null},"sdd": {"disk_id": 333,"volume_id": null}}`. how can I achieve this ??

Comment: @UmangPachaury For the former two approaches, replace `transpose | {devices: with_entries(...)}` with just `transpose | with_entries(...)`. For the latter two, replace `json='{"devices": {}}'` with just `json='{}'`, and `.devices |= . + {...}` with just `. += {...}` for the former, or `.devices["sd\($letter)"] += ...` with just `.["sd\($letter)"] += ...` for the latter of the two.